# TypeError: an integer is required (got type pygame.Rect)

Tags: python, pygame

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/untitled12/zmeika big game.py", line 135, in 
>       gameOver()
>     File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/untitled12/zmeika big game.py", line 51, in gameOver
>       playSurface.blit(gaOSurface,gaORectangular,gaOtSurface,gaotRectangular)
>   TypeError: an integer is required (got type pygame.Rect)

P.S Я пытался добавить предложения содержимого которого сколько время в игре вы проверили ,  line 47 и появилась вот такая ошибка.

```
import pygame.examples.stars, random,sys,time
    pygame.init()
    pygame.examples.stars.main()
    def eror():
        eror =  pygame.init()
        if eror[1] == 0:
            print("Program work")
        else:
            print("Errors detected")
            sys.exit()


t1 = time.time()

playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Змейка")
position = [50, 50]  # Координаты питончика
body = [[80, 50], [70, 50], [60, 50]]  # Структура тела питончика
bait = [random.randrange(1, 80) * 10, random.randrange(1, 60) * 10]
baitVisible = True  #
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()
direction = 'RIGHT'
changeto = direction
score = len(body)  # Задание 2. Задаем первичное значение длины тела питона

# color = pygame.Color(r, g, b)

white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)  # фон
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)  # конец игры
red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)  # шрифт
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)  # питончик
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
lightslateblue = pygame.Color(0, 200, 255)  # пища для питончика

def music():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)  # Задание 6. Зацикливаем музыку
def gameOver():  # Задание 4. Описание работы функции gameOver()
    gaOFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond',48)  # Создаем объект Font из системных шрифтов c параметрами имя = 'Garamond', размер = 48, жирный = False, курсив = False, и присваиваем ему имя gaoFont
    gaOSurface = gaOFont.render('Game over!Your score {}'.format(score),True,red)  # Создаем новую поверхность с текстом 'Game over!', буквы которого будут сглажены и иметь красный цвет и прозрачный фон. Присваиваем новому объекту имя gaoSurface
    gaORectangular = gaOSurface.get_rect()  # Преобразование поверхности gaOSurface  в прямоугольную при помощи функции get_rect()
    gaORectangular.midtop = (400,25)  # Выравнивание прямоугольной  поверхности (объекта) gaORectangular по координатам X (left) и Y(top)(400, 25)

    gaOtFont = pygame.font.SysFont ('Garamond',38)
    gaOtSurface = gaOtFont.render('Time in game:'+str(int(t1)), True,red)
    gaotRectangular = gaOtSurface.get_rect()
    gaotRectangular.midtop = (400,40)
    playSurface.fill(black)  # Задание 3. Очищаем игровое поле и заполняем его белым цветом RGB (white). В результате в конце игры на белом фоне видим текст "Game over!" и длину тела питона (счет)
    playSurface.blit(gaOSurface,gaORectangular,gaOtSurface,gaotRectangular)  # Прорисовывает объекты gaOSurface и gaORectangular поверх имеющихся изображений
    # Отрабатывает функция showScore() с аргументом choice = 2
    pygame.display.flip()  # Обновление содержимого всего экрана
    time.sleep(10)  # Приостановка выполнения программы на 10 секунд
    pygame.quit()  # Закрытие (выход, деинициализация) модюля pygame, программа продолжает работать
    sys.exit()  # Выход из python


def showScore(choice=1):

    gaOFoNt = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 14)
    gaoSurface = gaOFoNt.render('Правила игры:'
                                , True, red)
    gaorectangular = gaoSurface.get_rect()
    gaorectangular.midtop = (800, 20)
    playSurface.blit(gaoSurface,
                     gaorectangular)

    gaO2FoNt = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 14)
    gao2Surface = gaO2FoNt.render('esc - выход из игры,m - включить музыку'
                                  , True, red)
    gao2rectangular = gao2Surface.get_rect()
    gao2rectangular.midtop = (770, 45)
    playSurface.blit(gao2Surface,
                     gao2rectangular)
    gaO3FoNt = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 14)
    gao3Surface = gaO3FoNt.render('r - перезапуск игры,n - выключить музыку'
                                  , True, red)
    gao3rectangular = gao3Surface.get_rect()
    gao3rectangular.midtop = (770, 70)
    playSurface.blit(gao3Surface,
                     gao3rectangular)
    gaO4FoNt = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 14)
    gao4Surface = gaO4FoNt.render('W A S D или стики - управление,это всё,Удачи! '
                                  , True, red)
    gao4rectangular = gao4Surface.get_rect()
    gao4rectangular.midtop = (750, 95)
    playSurface.blit(gao4Surface,
                     gao4rectangular)
    pygame.display.flip()




    score2Font = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 18)
    score2Surface = score2Font.render('Длина питона:{0}'.format(score), True,
                                    red)

    score2Rect = score2Surface.get_rect()
    scoreRectangular = score2Surface.get_rect()



    scoreRectangular.midtop = (400, 25)

    playSurface.blit(score2Surface,score2Rect)
    pygame.display.flip()  # Обновление содержимого всего экрана

screen=pygame.display.set_mode()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
bk = pygame.image.load("imgres.jpg").convert()
bk = pygame.transform.scale(bk, (900, 700))

while True:
    screen.blit(bk, [0,0])

    clock.tick(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                changeto = 'RIGHT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                changeto = 'LEFT'
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                changeto = 'UP'
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                changeto = 'DOWN'

                # pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.QUIT)) # Задание 5. На экране выходило сообщение, что  имя QUIT не определено, т.к. такой переменной мы не задавали. Если внутри функции Event() вписать pygame.QUIT- то все ок
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:

               gameOver()

               time.sleep(10)
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()


            if event.key == ord('r'):
                gao228 = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond',48)
                gaOurface = gao228.render('Игра перезагружаеться!', True,
                                            red, )  # Создаем новую поверхность с текстом 'Game over!', буквы которого будут сглажены и иметь красный цвет и прозрачный фон. Присваиваем новому объекту имя gaoSurface
                playSurface.fill(lightslateblue)
                gaORectangular2 = gaOurface.get_rect()  # Преобразование поверхности gaOSurface  в прямоугольную при помощи функции get_rect()
                gaORectangular2.midtop = (400,
                                         25)

                position = [50, 50]
                body = [[80, 50], [70, 50], [60, 50]]
                playSurface.blit(gaOurface,
                                 gaORectangular2)
                pygame.display.flip()

                time.sleep(3)





            if event.key == ord('m'):
                music()
            if event.key == ord('n'):  # Задание 6. Задаем событие при нажатии клавиши "n"
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()  # проигрывание музыки останавливается

               # Работа с направлениями движения питончика









    if direction != 'LEFT' and changeto == 'RIGHT':
        direction = 'RIGHT'
    if direction != 'RIGHT' and changeto == 'LEFT':
        direction = 'LEFT'
    if direction != 'DOWN' and changeto == 'UP':
        direction = 'UP'
    if direction != 'UP' and changeto == 'DOWN':
        direction = 'DOWN'

    # Изменение позиций в зависимости от направления
    if direction == 'RIGHT':
        position[0] += 10
    if direction == 'LEFT':
        position[0] -= 10
    if direction == 'UP':
        position[1] -= 10
    if direction == 'DOWN':
        position[1] += 10

    # Работа над длиной тела питончика, увеличение счета в случае поедания пищи
    body.insert(0, list(position))
    if position[0] == bait[0] and position[1] == bait[1]:
        baitVisible = False
    else:
        body.pop()
        score = len(body) # Задание 2. После съедания питоном пищи, присваиваем переменной score новое значение длины его тела

    # Видимость пищи на карте
    if baitVisible == False:
        baitVisible = True
        bait = [random.randrange(1, 80) * 10, random.randrange(1, 60) * 10]



    for element in body:
        pygame.draw.rect(playSurface, green, pygame.Rect(element[0], element[1], 10, 10))

    # Прорисовываем пищу для питончика
    pygame.draw.rect(playSurface, lightslateblue, pygame.Rect(bait[0], bait[1], 10, 10))

    # Запрещаем  питончику покидать пределы игрового поля
    if position[0] > 790 or position[0] < 0:
        position[0] = 400
    if position[1] > 590 or position[1] < 0:
        position[1] = 300

    # Лишаем питончика возможности кушать самого себя

    for element in body[1:]:
                     # Задание 1. Проход циклом for по элементам списка (координатам) тела питона, начиная со второй позиции(индекс[1], а можно и с пятой, т.к. ближе пятой позиции[4:] своего тела питон укусить не может)
        if position[0] == element[0] and position[1] == element[1]:
              # Задание 1. Проверка условия совпадения координат головы питона (X, Y или индексы [0], [1] элементов списка position) с соответствующими координатами элементов списка body
            position = [50, 50]  # Координаты питончика
            body = [[80, 50], [70, 50], [60, 50]]  # Структура тела питончика

    showScore()
    pygame.display.flip()
    playSurface.fill (white)
    fpsController.tick(15 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Сигнатура метода .blit:

```
blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect
```

То есть 2 или 3 Rect и один флаг.
А вы передаете 4 Rect:

```
playSurface.blit(gaOSurface,gaORectangular,gaOtSurface,gaotRectangular)
```